# Relation between Kernel density estimation and Reproducing kernel Hilbert space?

Tags: st.statistics, integral-kernel

The procedure of kernel density estimation using a kernel $K$ is very similar to the construction of an RKHS from the kernel $K(x,y) = K(x-y).$ However, this viewpoint is not mentioned every place I have looked at.

Has there been any literature about how this viewpoint can be helpful?